# How to move home using relative path

Tags: linux, assignment

The question is "Your current directory is cambridge. Move to your home directory using a relative pathname (don't use cd by itself for this move)" but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.. I tried everything.

[image]

Comment: If you really had tried everything, you would have solved it. What did you try?

Comment: I tried cd ~ , cd /../../ , cd home, and others I cannot recall. It is my second day ever using Linux, this is for an assignment in school

Comment: `~` expands to the absolute path of your home. Relative movements means starting from where you are. So where do you want to move relatively (up or down? how many levels?)

Comment: It is asking me to move to the home directory. That is outside of sample_dir, but I don't know how far up since it wont let me type pwd or ls to see.

Comment: No `pwd`? Odd enough. Do you know your home? (hint - stored in shell variable `HOME`). Are you sure it is not meant to be "sample_dir"? How would you move there?

Comment: @Fiximan This is not a shell: it it an exercise wrapper which just matches the user's input against a short list of valid answers, and tells you off. If you don't know where sample_dir is, you can't construct a valid command except by trying cd .., cd ../.. etc until you get lucky. There may be a trick answer, but the OP can't be expected to find it on day 2. If it doesn't accept `ch $HOME` and wont answer `pwd`, and there are no Hints, the course itself sucks.

Comment: don't post text as text. I can't read it. It violates accessibility guidelines, and can't be read by blind people. Edit the question to include the text.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I love you<3 The answer was cd ../..
I don't know why I didn't think of that. I always thought you need a '/' at the end to wrap it off.

Comment: @AASFLC cd ../.. and cd ../../ will take you to the same place and both work - on a normal system that is. Maybe the course wrapper has the answer set defined too strictly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tree diagram does not show where home is, as you've mentioned. If it's the directory below "sample_dir", `cd ../..` will take you there. If it is "sample_dir", `cd ..` will do it.

Comment: Thank you so much. cd ../.. ended up being the answer!

Answer (score 0):

what works for most distributions it to just use tilde `~`.

That takes you directly to your home directory.

Comment: I agree with you. And that works in any other terminal that I use. But this only wants a specific answer, and I can't find it. I tried 'cd ~' , 'cd ~/' and almost everything else. But it's not accepting them as answers..

Comment: Reverie: `~` is expanding to `$HOME` which itself is an absolute path. The question deals with a relative movement.

Comment: @Reverie In my Bash, 4.3.48, `~` says `bash: /home/paul: Is a directory`. I think it expands ~ and tries to execute it as a command.